# Suma de una cadena de numeros en bash linux

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell, shell-script

Estoy aprendiendo como hacer scripts en bash linux, empecé realizando un calculadora sencilla que me suma dos números. La duda que tengo es ¿Cómo hago una calculadora que me sume n cantidad de dígitos sin crear una infinidad de variables?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nosotros no podemos proporcionar un código, sino ayudarte. Por ello es importante que le des a [edit] para añadir qué hiciste y qué no te funciona. Revisa también [ask].

Comment: Probablemente lo que buscas es el uso de `shift`. De momento publica lo que has hecho hasta ahora y vemos cómo podedmos implementaron en tu código, ok?

Comment: Porque infinidad de variables? `calculadora(){ sum=0; for i in "$@"; do sum=$((sum + i)); done; echo $sum; }`  y `calculadora 12 43 5 7 8`.